# I can not set cookie inside setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, settimeout

I am using Angularjs ngCookies, but I can not set the cookie inside setTimeout function?

```js
setTimeout(function () {
       $cookieStore.put('valid', false)
}, 0)
```

if you check the cookie inside the setTimeout function you can see the value,
but if you check the cookie on next request you couldn't find it !!!!

I want to understand the reason

Answer (score 0):

I would try with angular's wrapper for settimeout
 https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Mixing non angular functions in always has mixed results for me.

They explain why [here](https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq/angularjs-use-timeout-not-settimeout)